# Navigation after ng build --prod not working

Tags: angular, mean-stack

After i set up anything and running `ng build --prod` my navigation doesn't work. So my links on my buttons are still fine. If i click on a button which goes to lets say `www.domain.tld/login` everything works. But if i now directly want to enter that page by typing the url into my browser it says

> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

I developed an app based on the MEAN-Stack using angular 4

Inside my development environment (local) everything works fine, so there i can call localhost:4200/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use deep links you have to configure your application server the right way. In development it is working fine, because nodejs already is configured for that feature.

For more information about your server you can check if there is a solution for your environment in the [angular docu](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)